# SIP-client supporting playing audio to callee

Tags: audio, phone, voip

I am seeking a SIP-client that allows playing audio file to the answerer, wav, mp3, mp4, no matter which type of audio. Are there any option besides [command-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845302/play-audio-file-over-voip) ones?

I tried [Phoner](https://phoner.de/), it claims to support this but he does this very bad. The person I am calling to cannot hear almost nothing, just a mumbling and whispering. The quality of the audio rendering is very bad.

Any suggestions? I am open both to Desktop (incl. Linux) and Android options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

baresip: https://github.com/baresip/baresip - command line, there are few modules for remote control though (including webserver), so it might be used with external GUI.

tSIP: http://tomeko.net/software/SIPclient/ - Windows only; can play wav as default source, when button is pressed and/or controlled by script ("Lenny" example).

Using mp3 or mp4 files (most likely aac audio) requires avformat baresip module or using tSIP version with video support. Single mp4 file can be actually used as both audio source and video source for video call.

Using virtual audio device is another option.

Comment: thanks, will try tSIP. Which one has the most high quality: tSIP or virtual device?

Comment: Quality would be mostly limited by codec being used for the call and/or final call destination - quite possibly it would be PSTN-like.